# C# Roslyn replace methods

Tags: c#, mono, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to refactor (add a prefix) local declared methods and their usage in `.cs` files

What is the best practice to accomplish that ?

My current code only deals with declarations

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace CodeScanner { 
  internal sealed class Fixer : CSharpSyntaxRewriter {
    public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node) {
      base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);
      // replace usages
      return node;
    }
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node) {
      base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
      return node.ReplaceNode(node, SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
          node.AttributeLists,
          node.Modifiers,
          node.ReturnType,
          node.ExplicitInterfaceSpecifier,
          SyntaxFactory.Identifier("prefix_" + node.Identifier.Value),
          node.TypeParameterList,
          node.ParameterList,
          node.ConstraintClauses,
          node.Body,
          node.ExpressionBody));
    }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText("./test.cs"));
      var rewriter = new Fixer();
      var result = rewriter.Visit(tree.GetRoot());
      Console.WriteLine(result.ToFullString());
    }
  }
}
```

Input file

```
using System;

namespace TopLevel
{
  class Bar {
    public void test1(){}

    public void test2(){ Console.WriteLine("str"); }

    public void Fizz() {
      Console.WriteLine(test1());
      Console.WriteLine(test1(test2()));
      test2();
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
using System;

namespace TopLevel
{
  class Bar {
    public void prefix_test1(){}

    public void prefix_test2(){ Console.WriteLine("str"); }

    public void prefix_Fizz() {
      Console.WriteLine(test1());
      Console.WriteLine(test1(test2()));
      test2();
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output (changes @ Fizz ):

```
using System;

namespace TopLevel
{
  class Bar {
    public void prefix_test1(){}

    public void prefix_test2(){ Console.WriteLine("str"); }

    public void prefix_Fizz() {
      Console.WriteLine(prefix_test1());
      Console.WriteLine(prefix_test1(prefix_test2()));
      prefix_test2();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the exact problem?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: I see his problem is the method definition has been renamed but the references to it was not. I think it should be change `Console.WriteLine(test1());` -> `Console.WriteLine(prefix_test1());`

Comment: @LeVu I get that, it's just that I'm not sure what the problem is writing the code. The question is not precise enough.

Comment: I want to rename all declared methods, is it not clear?

Comment: @whoopdedoo Your requirements are clear. What is not clear to me is what _specific_ problem is preventing you from writing the code.

Comment: Knowledge and experience with Rosyln

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code that matches the requirements you set.

See on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0NGjaX)

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO;
using static Globals;

tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText("Test.cs"));
compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("HelloWorld").AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
new Finder().Visit(tree.GetRoot());
Console.WriteLine(new Rewriter().Visit(tree.GetRoot()).NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString());

public static class Globals
{
    public static SyntaxTree tree;
    public static CompilationUnitSyntax root;
    public static CSharpCompilation compilation;
    public static SemanticModel model;
    public static Dictionary<IMethodSymbol, string> renames = new();
}

public sealed class Finder : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
        renames.Add(model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node), "prefix_" + node.Identifier.Value);
    }
}

public sealed class Rewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax mds)
    {
        IMethodSymbol symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(mds);
        mds = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)base.VisitMethodDeclaration(mds);
        if (renames.TryGetValue(symbol, out string newName))
            mds = mds.ReplaceToken(mds.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier(newName));
        return mds;
    }

    [return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
    public override SyntaxNode Visit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        node = base.Visit(node);
        if (node is SimpleNameSyntax sns &&
            model.GetSymbolInfo(sns) is { Symbol: IMethodSymbol ms } && renames.TryGetValue(ms, out string newName)
        )
            node = sns.ReplaceToken(sns.Identifier, SyntaxFactory.Identifier(newName));
        return node;
    }
}
```